# unknown option short form m

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line, command

I am trying to run MySQL from the windows command line.  I am using version 5.6 of MySQL.  The command I am trying to run from cmd.exe in windows 7 is:

```
mysql --local-infile -uroot -myrootpassword mydatabasename
```

But the windows cmd.exe command line client is giving me the following error message:

```
MySQL: unknown option '-m'
```

I found one reference to a short option '-m' that was added in an earlier version of MySQL, but have been unable to relocate that reference to read it more closely after I browsed to other pages.

How do I get past this error so that I can set my database to allow data importation from a local infile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `> mysql --local-infile -uroot -myrootpassword mydatabasename
>                                ↑
>                                └─` Here's the "-m"

I'm guessing you meant to use the `-p` option to supply the password.

> `> mysql --local-infile -uroot -pmyrootpassword mydatabasename`